# Show list of questions user closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

It would be good to have a way to see all the duplicate questions I have closed in the past. Maybe a new activity tab that shows all the questions I closed.

The reason for this is that when I close a question I usually leave the window open for a long time just to see if the OP is having problem with the duplicate or if the question is not a duplicate but just poorly phrased by OP.

Sometimes, OP uses @username to reply to me to say "thanks", to complain that the question is not a duplicate or to mention that the duplicate has been tried before posting that question. In that case, I use the comment section to help OP more or I re-open the question for another person to help if the problem is truly unique.

The problem is that some OP don't even know how to use @username to reply to people and they expect me to magically see their comment or their edit by just editing their question with new information. When this happen, I won't be notified. Also, the notification system seem to fail on my account once in a while and I find out that I got a reply weeks later when I manually search for that question again. I am getting tired of having windows of questions I've closed to be open for few hours.

It would be easier and helpful to go to the activity tab on my profile and check on these questions I closed to see I need to take further actions.

**EDIT:**

I don't care about this list on questions many(4) other people also flagged as duplicate before me since *others agreed that the question is a duplicate*. I care about this only when I use a *gold tag badge* to close a question.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer?tab=votes&sort=closure) work?

Comment: I just saw this. That's basically a tab(Closure) under another tab(Votes) and under another tab(Activity). Didn't even know that existed. Although it does not *fully* solve the issue. It shows all the votes including questions that are not closed and there is a lot of them. I need to see questions that I closed as a duplicate and is no longer open not the ones I voted to close but did not close due to tag privileges.

Comment: Use SEDE http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/724747 if you can live with the weekly refresh.

Comment: It's missing the latest closed question which are the ones I care the most for. Other than that, it looks fine when bookmarked.

Comment: Aren't you rather looking for a list of canonical duplicates, a.k.a. a FAQ? It's not as useful to see which dupes we picked ourselves, as to see which dupes a lot of people picked.

Comment: SO needs persons like you. :-)

Comment: @Lundin No, I am looking for a list of questions I closed just like list of questions I asked or answered.

Comment: You only think you want this feature, but you really want are 2 distinct other features :) The first is the ability to subscribe to a sort of feed/notifications on a question because you probably have the same problem with other questions you've commented on (w/wo closing) and adding everything into the favorites tab is a nightmare. The second is a popup for new users when writing comments, similar to the ones that pop when writing a question, that tells them to use `@username` to reply to a user (one per comment). I know this is what you want because we play the same way on SO.

Comment: Yes, those would be awesome but then that would be too much thing to ask. Just wanted a simple list. I though about using favorites tab but I value my favorites questions/answers and don't want to mess with that.

Comment: Yes, I know. And you missed notifying me with @ but I was ready for this and so I reply quickly :D I think that asking for the popup on comments is not much to ask and I would guess it was suggested somewhere before. In any case, the idea might need reinforcing.

Comment: @user1803551 Ok. As for "@", I didn't put it on my last comment on purpose. I believe that if you don't use it, it will notify the last comment under the question/answer. I noticed this but not entirely sure. It looks like the window must be closed in order to be notified. Can anyone verify?

Comment: I don't think it works that way. I think it would have notified me only if I was the only other person to comment (so I'm the only valid target for the comment). I didn't receive a notification but I will close the SO tabs and will come back in an hour or so if you want to reply here without @ to test.

Comment: Ok. I though that's how it worked since I joined this site. Anyways, check back and let me know if you were notified.

Comment: Nope, no notification. You can comment on a post I made where there are no other comments and I will reply without @ and you should be notified.

Comment: @user1803551 I see that happens in question/answer only. Thanks for verifying. I've been doing this for a long time and now I feel bad for those people that thought I ignored them.